# Unmet dependencies: nvidia-alternative breaks nvidida-tesla-alternative

Tags: apt, kali-linux, nvidia

Good day.

I'm attempting to upgrade my Kali Linux system, however I am running into an issue i'm ignorant of:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-alternative : Breaks: nvidia-tesla-alternative (> 0) but 510.85.02-1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Above is the output from executing the command `sudo apt update`. At the moment, I don't understand what is breaking what, and how to fix said issue. I assume `nvidia-alternative` is breaking `nvidia-tesla-alternative`, however it tells me that the next update of `nvidia-tesla-alternative` will be installed? A cursory search of this issue doesn't bring up anything useless, not even similarities to the issue I am facing.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Thanks in advance,
DJM.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Please don't ask me why or how this fixed the problem, I do not know. I ran full-upgrade and it fixed it.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```